# Using Tkinter in Python Label does not recognize anchor=CENTER

Tags: python, tkinter, label, justify

I am new to tkinter and have been using:

```
from tkinter import *
```

but have read this is bad practice. 
I rewrote a very small bit of code to start using the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

However when I run the rest of the code. I get the error:
`label.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.35, anchor=CENTER)
NameError: name 'CENTER' is not defined`

```
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="I am a label widget")
label.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.35, anchor=CENTER)    
button = tk.Button(root, text="I am a button")
label.pack()
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Is this a namespace issue? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: As with the other places where you added `tk.`, you need `tk.CENTER`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much for such a quick response. That solved the issue. I should have thought that not just functions/classes etc would need the extension.

Answer (score 0):

`*` gets all the sub packages.  Using `import tkinter as tk` just changes the name of the package from tkinter to tk.

You have not told your script `CENTER` is part of tkinter.  (you did this automatically when you used `*`) but now you must do by explicitly telling `CENTER` is part of tkinter:

```
tk.CENTER
```

Answer (score 0):

`CENTER` is a variable(actually they usually are referred to as constants) of [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) module which equals to `'center'`. So simply replace the line with:

```
label.place(..., anchor='center')
```